# How can i get a class name added by javascript

Tags: javascript

In the code below i'm adding an active class `active` when the user click on the `li`.

when i do `document.querySelector(".active");` to select the li that contain the active class the result is always the first li that contain the active class by default.

How can i get the active class when it's added `onclick` by the javascript?

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");
let lisArray = Array.from(lis);

lisArray.forEach((li) => {
  li.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    lisArray.forEach((ele) => {
      ele.classList.remove("active");
    });
    li.classList.add("active");
    document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor =
      e.currentTarget.dataset.cont;
    window.localStorage.setItem("color", e.currentTarget.dataset.cont);
  });
});

if(window.localStorage.getItem("color")){
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.getItem("color");
}else{
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}

let active = document.querySelector(".active");
console.log(active);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 16px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: Arial;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

ul li {
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li:first-of-type {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

ul li:first-of-type.active body {
  background-color: red;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

ul li.active,
ul li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="active" data-cont="white"></li>
  <li data-cont="red"></li>
  <li data-cont="green"></li>
  <li data-cont="deepskyblue"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You want to get the element that is having the class="active" when user clicks on the li?

Comment: yes the javascript add a class active each time he click on a diferent li i want to have the class active

Comment: The last two lines of you code, will set the variable 'active' to be the element that is active when you load this script. you should move this line into the function in the event listener

Comment: how can i get the active that is click it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the active element in the click function:

```
let lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");
let lisArray = Array.from(lis);
let active;

lisArray.forEach((li) => {
  li.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    lisArray.forEach((ele) => {
      ele.classList.remove("active");
    });
    li.classList.add("active");
    active = li;
    console.log(li);
    document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor =
      e.currentTarget.dataset.cont;
    window.localStorage.setItem("color", e.currentTarget.dataset.cont);
  });
});

if (window.localStorage.getItem("color")) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.getItem("color");
} else {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}

active = document.querySelector(".active");
console.log(active);
```